# docker-compose up and docker-compose exec don't use the same container name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Good morning.

I am working with Docker for Windows 19.03.8, build afacb8b;   running on Windows Server 2019 (10.0.17763.1039)

when I run Docker-Compose *up* -dV it says something like:

```
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating docker_python-base_1 ... done
Creating docker_msbuild_1 ... done
```

but when I then use Docker-Compose *exec*, it says:
`ERROR: No container found for msbuild_1`

in other words, the UP and the EXEC are not using the same (default?) container name.

Al-waleed Shihadeh asked for more info  (thanks you !!!!).  so....

my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    python-base-srv:
        build:
            context: ./images/python-base
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-PythonBase
        image: mycompany/builds-win-base-python:3.7.6
        volumes:
        - ../../..:C:/bldroot
        command: powershell -NoExit -NonInteractive

    msbuild-srv:
        build:
            context: ./images/msbuild
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-msbuild
        image: mycompany/builds-win-msbuild:15.0
        volumes: 
        - ../../..:C:/bldroot
        depends_on: 
        - python-base-srv
        command: powershell -NoExit -NonInteractive
```

Dockerfile-msbuild:

```
# escape=`

ARG FROM_IMAGE=mycompany/builds-win-base-python

FROM ${FROM_IMAGE} AS build
    SHELL [ "powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';" ]

    RUN Invoke-WebRequest 'https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe' -OutFile C:\Downloads\vs_buildtools.exe -UseBasicParsing ; `
        Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Downloads\vs_buildtools.exe' -Wait `
          -ArgumentList `
            '--quiet', `
            '--norestart', `
            '--locale en-US', `
            '--installPath C:\BuildTools', `
            '--nocache', `
            '--addProductLang en-US', `
            '--add Microsoft.Net.Component.3.5.DeveloperTools', `
            '--add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack', `
            '--add Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.6.1.DeveloperTools', `
            '--add Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.6.2.DeveloperTools', `
            '--add Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.TargetingPacks.Common', `
            '--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.WinXP' ; `
        Remove-Item c:\Downloads\vs_buildtools.exe -Force

    RUN $PATH = $env:PATH + ';C:\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin' ; `
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $PATH

    # Start developer command prompt before running the specified command (from RUN/EXEC commandline)
    COPY ["VsDevCmdPowerShell.bat", "C:\\BuildTools\\"]
    ENTRYPOINT ["cmd", "/k", "C:\\BuildTools\\VsDevCmdPowerShell.bat"]
```

Dockerfile-PythonBase:

```
# escape=`

ARG FROM_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

FROM ${FROM_IMAGE} AS python-base
    SHELL [ "powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';" ]
    RUN `
        New-Item -Path C:\Downloads -ItemType Directory ; `
        New-Item -Path C:\path -ItemType Directory ; `
        `
        $PATH = 'C:\path;' + $env:PATH ; `
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $PATH ; `
        `
        Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.6/python-3.7.6.exe' -OutFile c:\Downloads\python-installer.exe -UseBasicParsing ; `
        Start-Process c:\Downloads\python-installer.exe -ArgumentList '/quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1' -Wait ; `
        Remove-Item c:\Downloads\python-installer.exe -Force

CMD ["powershell", "-NoExit", "-NoLogo", "cmd", "/c ver", ";", "python", "--version", ";", "nuget", "help | select -First 1", ";"]
```

Outputs:

```
C:\work\docker> docker-compose up -dV msbuild-srv
Recreating docker_python-base-srv_1 ... done
Recreating docker_msbuild-srv_1     ... done

C:\work\docker> docker-compose ps
          Name                        Command               State    Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker_msbuild-srv_1       cmd /k C:\BuildTools\VsDev ...   Exit 0
docker_python-base-srv_1   powershell -NoExit -NonInt ...   Exit 0

C:\work\docker> docker logs docker_msbuild-srv_1

Call VsDevCmd.bat to setup environment . . .

C:\>call C:\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************

powershell -NoExit -NonInteractive
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\>

C:\>
C:\work\docker>
```

so - it is not leaving the containers running in the compose UP step like it should.

docker run -it  works fine:
`docker container run -it --name msbuildTesting -v C:/work:C:/bldroot -w c:\bldroot\build mycompany/builds-win-msbuild`

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your containers are exiting directly after `docker-compose up`, you can verify this by issuing these commands

```
docker-compose ps
```

or

```
docker ps -a
```

you also can check the reason why the containers exited by checking the logs

```
docker logs ${container_name}
```

Notes:
 1. You should use this command to connect to the container `docker-compose exec msbuild ${command}`

Comment: Ug.  Thank you Al-waleed Shihadeh.   Yes, they are exiting.

Comment: I can't get linebreaks to work in here :-(

`C:\docker> docker-compose ps
          Name                        Command               State    Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker_msbuild-srv_1       cmd /k C:\BuildTools\VsDev ...   Exit 0
docker_python-base-srv_1   powershell -NoExit -NonInt ...   Exit 0`

`C:\docker> docker logs docker_python-base-srv_1
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\>

C:\docker>`

I tried to add this to yml: `command: powershell -NoExit -NonInteractive`

Comment: can you update the question, it is hard to read this way. maybe also add the docker files to your containers